# Problems with user defined app.config data

Tags: c#, app-config, configurationmanager

I have some problems to create a fully implemented ConfigurationCollection with the following user defined section in the app.config.file

```
<OPCSection>
    <OPCDefinitions tab_id="9">
      <OPC column_id="G" datatypename="State" nameontab="State" />
      <OPC column_id="H" datatypename="Fault1" nameontab="Front end positon not reached" />
      <OPC column_id="I" datatypename="Fault2" nameontab="Rear end positon not reached" />
    </OPCDefinitions>
    <OPCDefinitions tab_id="10">
      <OPC column_id="G" datatypename="State" nameontab="State" />
      <OPC column_id="H" datatypename="Fault1" nameontab="Front end positon not reached" />
      <OPC column_id="I" datatypename="Fault2" nameontab="Rear end positon not reached" />
    </OPCDefinitions>
  </OPCSection>
```

I had this section before but I got an error (item is already added)...

```
  <OPCSection>
    <OPCDefinitions>
      <add tab_id="9" column_id="G" datatypename="State" nameontab="State" />
      <add tab_id="9" column_id="H" datatypename="Fault1" nameontab="Front end positon not reached" />
      <add tab_id="10" column_id="H" datatypename="Fault1" nameontab="Front end positon not reached" />
      <add tab_id="10" column_id="I" datatypename="Fault2" nameontab="Rear end positon not reached" />
    </OPCDefinitions>
  </OPCSection>
```

What I need now is a class where I can access these fields from. I also want to access those fields by name like e.g.

classname.ColumnID

I hope someone can help me out to get this...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up the [documentation for ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It supports user defined appSettings like here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Setting1" value="May 5, 2014"/>
    <add key="Setting2" value="May 6, 2014"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have updated by post so you can see what I was trying before. Unfortunately I am not able to post my c# code in which I implement the ConfigurationElements ConfigurationCollection etc.